# Factorizing complex numbers

Tags: mathematics

Let's have the following number $(3i-\frac{5}{3})^3$. What is the trick to factorizing this number in more than one way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given number is 1/27 times the cube of 9i-5. That Gaussian integer has norm 9^2+5^2=81+25=106=2.53 and accordingly 9i+5 factorizes into Gaussian primes as (1+i)(2+7i), and therefore we can factor your number in lots of different ways by grouping three lots of (1+i), three lots of (2+7i), and three lots of 1/3 in whatever way we prefer.

(Your question seems to be asking us to guess what particular way of doing it happens to be in your mind, but obviously that's not a puzzle but a guessing game.)